# Syntastic cpp : fatal error "QApplication: no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, qt, vim, syntastic

not knowing Perl, I am unable to configure syntastic for newer c++ libraries that i experiment on. Vim refused to recognize the header files . here is a program which compiles fine but syntastic shows an error on it:

```
 #include <QApplication>            <----------- line of error as in title
 #include <QPushButton>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QPushButton hello("Hello world!");
     hello.resize(100, 30);

     hello.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

this is my cpp.vim file inside syntax-checkers subdirectory of vim . note i have tried to add the path to Qt4 in this but no use

```
" in order to also check header files add this to your .vimrc:
" (this usually creates a .gch file in your source directory)
"
"   let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1
"
" To disable the search of included header files after special
" libraries like gtk and glib add this line to your .vimrc:
"
"  let g:syntastic_cpp_no_include_search = 1
"
" To enable header files being re-checked on every file write add the
" following line to your .vimrc. Otherwise the header files are checked only
" one time on initially loading the file.
" In order to force syntastic to refresh the header includes simply
" unlet b:syntastic_cpp_includes. Then the header files are being re-checked
" on the next file write.
"
"   let g:syntastic_cpp_auto_refresh_includes = 1
"
" Alternatively you can set the buffer local variable b:syntastic_cpp_cflags.
" If this variable is set for the current buffer no search for additional
" libraries is done. I.e. set the variable like this:
"
"   let b:syntastic_cpp_cflags = ' -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4'
"
" Moreover it is possible to add additional compiler options to the syntax
" checking execution via the variable 'g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options':
"
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = ' -std=c++0x'

if exists('loaded_cpp_syntax_checker')
    finish
endif
let loaded_cpp_syntax_checker = 1

if !executable('g++')
    finish
endif

let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

function! SyntaxCheckers_cpp_GetLocList()
    let makeprg = 'g++ -fsyntax-only '.shellescape(expand('%'))
    let errorformat =  '%-G%f:%s:,%f:%l:%c: %m,%f:%l: %m'

    if expand('%') =~? '\%(.h\|.hpp\|.hh\)$'
        if exists('g:syntastic_cpp_check_header')
            let makeprg = 'g++ -c '.shellescape(expand('%'))
        else
            return []
        endif
    endif

    if exists('g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options')
        let makeprg .= g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options
    endif

    if !exists('b:syntastic_cpp_cflags')
        if !exists('g:syntastic_cpp_no_include_search') ||
                    \ g:syntastic_cpp_no_include_search != 1
            if exists('g:syntastic_cpp_auto_refresh_includes') &&
                        \ g:syntastic_cpp_auto_refresh_includes != 0
                let makeprg .= syntastic#c#SearchHeaders()
            else
                if !exists('b:syntastic_cpp_includes')
                    let b:syntastic_cpp_includes = syntastic#c#SearchHeaders()
                endif
                let makeprg .= b:syntastic_cpp_includes
            endif
        endif
    else
        let makeprg .= b:syntastic_cpp_cflags
    endif

    return SyntasticMake({ 'makeprg': makeprg, 'errorformat': errorformat })
endfunction
let &cpo = s:save_cpo
unlet s:save_cpo
let s:default_includes = [ '.', '..', 'include', 'includes' ]
let s:default_includes = [ '.', '..', 'include', 'includes','../include', '../includes' ]


 function! s:GetIncludeDirs()

     let include_dirs = s:default_includes
 endfunction
" vim: set et sts=4 sw=4:
```

and the syntastic relevant lines from my .gvimrc:

```
"===============================SYNTASTICSETTINGS================================================
"set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
"set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
"set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs = ['../include','include']
let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
let g:syntastic_quiet_warnings=1
set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=full
```

I would appreciate help on learning the workings of syntastic and syntax checkers as i suspect this problem will recur everytime i practice a different development kit. thanks

Comment: you defined the `g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs` in your cpp.vim (which you should not do anyway) and then redefined the same variable in your `.gvimrc`. I am no expert on QT but using the `g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs` should work. What command line do you use to compile your file that does work?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. . I build it using cmake, that pretty much automatically detects the package. I am trying to figure out the individual files. PS > I have removed the g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs from my cpp.vim file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I copied the latest files version hosted on 
https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

and now syntastic is not giving me problems anymore. The version i had  previously and that kept giving me problems is 
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736

Comment: This didn't fix the issue in my case. This answer does not explain what the problem was either.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting `syntastic_cpp_include_dirs` to `/usr/include/qt4/QtGui`? It looks like it is supposed to give the directory in which the header is located.

Comment: Yeah i did that.. tried different variations of that. not working

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add *all* the subdirectories of `/usr/include` to `syntastic_cpp_include_dirs`?